# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Python

Tags: python, django

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement `librabbitmq==1.6.1` (from versions: 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.4, 0.9.5, 0.9.6, 0.9.7, 0.9.8, 0.9.9, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 2.0.0)

I am getting similar error while install `librarabbitmq,numpy,supervisor,xattr,MySQL-python` there are specific versions i am trying to install and it pops out the same error while the version remain in the packages it can't find those.

The command used to install the package

```
pip install librabbitmq==1.6.1
```

the same goes for other packages as well

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the exact command you use to install packages? Most of the time the problems are there. Please also add your python version and whether or not you use virtual environments

Comment: That version of `librabbitmq` is available through `pip install librabbitmq==1.6.1`, but it looks like it's using old syntax and may not be compatible with your version of Python. My version of Python (3.9) complains about line 191 of the `setup.py`, on this: `except Exception, exc:` (which is indeed incorrect, those need to be in parentheses). Don't go and try to fix the code though - find a set of tools that work for the version of Python you need, or install a version of Python that matches the set of tools you need.